# Is there a bookmarklet that will let me email a selection from a website and its corresponding URL?

Tags: blog, bookmarklet

I use Posterous for blogging, and do all of my posting through Mail.app

I do a lot of kottke-sullivan-style posts in this format:

The New York Times [reports](http://www.nytimes.com):

```
Blah blah blah
```

Interesting.

But what should be a pretty easy process takes a lot of work, and it's too much work to get done on an iPad comfortably.

I'd like to have a bookmarklet where I could just select the paragraph (Blah Blah Blah above) to become the block quote and have it instantly create a new message in Mail.app or iOS Mail with the url in a link ready to turn into "The New York Times reports:" or "John Gruber riffs:", then the block quote, then I can just type in my comments and send it off.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use Posterous' [bookmarklet](http://posterous.com/help/bookmarklet) for posting to your posterous site.

[image: Bookmarklet]

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work for my purposes. One reason I use the email posting feature of Posterous is because I post to four blogs simultaneously (I teach four different courses and have a blog for each). It is easy to do this in an email, because you can put four address in the To: field. So, yes, that would work if I'm posting just to one class, but usually for interesting links I post to all four.

Comment: ah, Ok. I'm going to leave the answer here as a general reference, will see what I can dig up. @dru